# Help me make sense of this use of 'hitherto'

Tags: meaning

The role this word plays in the sentence's meaning is never automatically clear for me, but this one confuses me, it seems off. Exchanging it for "so far" or "up until that point" doesn't work here.

> In the present [20th] century, starting more or less with the work of
>   Ferdinand de Saussure, emphasis has been placed much more firmly than
>   **hitherto** on language as it is used rather than on how experts say that
>   it should be used.

Comment: It means "previously", or (as you've put it) "up until that point". Why do you think that "doesn't work here"?  In fact, the words "than hitherto/previously" are superfluous:  "... starting more or less with the work of Ferdinand de Saussure, emphasis has been placed much more firmly on [how] language ... is [actually] used ... than on how experts say that it should be used."

Comment: I think the word order plus me not knowing to read hitherto as 'previously' is what threw me off so much. Also it being superfluous as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

[When used as an adverb hitherto](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hitherto) indicates that something was true up until the time you are talking about.

> Prices tomorrow will be 20% more than hitherto.